# Magento 2 :- Checkout Page Postcode validation rule

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

I tried to change the post-code validation on the checkout page, but I can not find any solution. So please help me with it.How to change the validation rules on it my module.

Comment: Can u please tell me what u want?

Comment: Hi you can visit this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153233/validation-for-zip-code-field-on-checkout-page-in-magento-2 Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js then you see that you have a lot of rules to do the things.

for example I go to use this rule:

```
"validate-digits": [
            function(value) {
                return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || !/[^\d]/.test(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please enter a valid number in this field.')
        ],
```

I go to use this rule in my postcode input field. Then we have to override our checkout_index_index.xml in our module to put this rule

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">  
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->

                                                            <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I hope it is helpful